# How to detect code running forever when using CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I would like to compile and execute code from a string. Calling the method **ExecuteCode()** successfully works and returns a string value.  However, calling **ExecuteEndlessCode()** hangs the Console application. How can I detect that *CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync* is potentially executing code that is running forever?

```
public static string ExecuteEndlessCode()
{
     var script = @"string Run() { while(true){} return ""1"";} Run()";
     var result = CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<string>(script, null).Result;
     return result;            
}

public static string ExecuteCode()
{
     var script = @"string Run() { return ""1"";} Run()";
     var result = CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<string>(script, null).Result;
     return result;            
}
```

Comment: [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a timeout for the script, and execute the script execution inside a task, like this:

```
var script = @" int Run() { while(true){} return 1;} Run();";
var task = CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<string>(script, null)
if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout) != task)
{ // handle timeout
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good idea. Have you tried this out? I am not able to compile the fragment of code you provided.

Comment: I didn't, it's just a direction for you to implement

Comment: @lucidgold If you're copy-pasting verbatim, I'd expect it to fail. Missing a close parenthesis (just before the != task). But I agree with syscloud, use this as a jumping off point for how to think about the problem